# Name for this structured matrix with the $ij$th entry as $x^{i+j-2}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $x>0$. Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix with the $ij$th entry as 
$$[A]_{ij}=x^{i+j-2}$$
Does $A$ has a name or any known spectrum properties?

---

**EDIT:** After I post the question, I realized that it is trivial because 
$$A=yy^T$$
where $y=[1,x,x^2,\dots,x_{n-1}]^T$. So it is positive semi-definite and of rank one. The nonzero eigenvalue is $\|y\|^2$ and the eigenvector is $y$ and all the other eigenvalues are zero.

Comment: As it is or rank $1$ (for $x\ne 0$) its spectrum is a bit dull

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: thanks. I also realized that after I posted the question.

Comment: After all, no restriction on $x$ seems needed